# HTTP Client Patch method with Asp.net core 2.1, bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Using `HttpClient` to perform a PATCH method request is getting an bad request error

```
var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<ClientOrganisationRequestArgs>();
patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Name, clientOrganisationRequestArgs.Name);
var serializedDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);
var requestContent = new StringContent(serializedDoc, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PatchAsync(
    $"api/orgs/{clientOrganisationRequestArgs.ClientRefId}", requestContent);
```

Model

```
public class ClientOrganisationRequestArgs
{
    public int ClientRefId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DefaultTimezone => "AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY";
    public string CustomStylePath { get; set; }
}
```

Getting 400 with bad request

[image]

Postman also show an 500 internal server error with body as raw

[image]

Authorization and accept header

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.yellowfin.api-v1.3+json");
_authorizationHeader =
                $"{_authorizationHeader}, token={accessToken.SecurityToken}";
            
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                HeaderNames.Authorization, _authorizationHeader);
```

Comment: Are the authorization header and accept header sent correctly?

Comment: Based on the docs shown it is expecting simple `application/json` content type header but you have `application/json-patch+json` as content type

Answer (score 0):

You have `application/json-patch+json` as content type

```
//...

var requestContent = new StringContent(serializedDoc, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

//...
```

But based on the docs shown it is expecting simple `application/json` content type header

```
var requestContent = new StringContent(serializedDoc, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Also based on the example in the shown doc, the payload is a plain JSON document and does not really appear to be following the JSON Patch document format. This may result in the API not recognizing the request content.

I suggest serializing the payload to match the example given

```
string serializedDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientOrganisationRequestArgs);

StringContent requestContent = new StringContent(serializedDoc, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

string url = $"api/orgs/{clientOrganisationRequestArgs.ClientRefId}";

var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PatchAsync(url, requestContent);
```

assuming

```
public class ClientOrganisationRequestArgs {
    [JsonProperty("clientRefId")]
    public int ClientRefId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("defaultTimezone")]
    public string DefaultTimezone => "AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY";
    [JsonProperty("customStylePath")]
    public string CustomStylePath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well I am getting 500 internal server error, not sure what is the cause for that

Comment: @SanJaisy are you able to debug an see what is the actual error/exception. 500 could be anything

Comment: How can I debug what wrong, with that httpcall. On HttpClient I have only public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(   string requestUri,   HttpContent content); there is no implementation of it, quite not sure how to debug